# Why is lldb so painfully slow?

Tags: c, macos, lldb, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a very simple C program on OSX and the debugger is taking MINUTES for each step over instruction, with instructions as simple as doing a single multiplication. I've googled a lot and can't seem to find any explanation.

Note that I last did any C/C++ about 20 years ago and am just trying to understand the basic tools. I'm using VSCode on an M1 Macbook Air, running Ventura 13.2.1. I'm slightly confused about the relationship between clang, llvm, lldb, and gcc on OSX, but I've tried 2 different ways to invoke the debugger in VSCode, with same results.

When I start a debug session, the locals view in upper left of VSCode shows a spinny thing for several minutes before finally showing local variables. Each time I hit step forward (over, in, or out), it takes another several minutes to show the locals.

I also notice that the debugger is showing the current line of execution as 2 lines ahead of where the resolved locals imply the code actually is.

In Activity Monitor, the lldb-mi process is using 99-100% of presumable one of the CPU's cores.

I'm not doing anything fancy. I'm barely further than a simple Hello, World program here -- am creating a pixel buffer and doing a little math to calculate colors. When I run rather than debug, the output is mostly as expected, meaning the program "works".

Anyone have any troubleshooting steps or suggestions?

Comment: Does it work with just the command line (cc + lldb)?   How about Xcode?   If the answer to both of those is no, VS is your likely culprit.

Comment: I use Xcode, personally.  It's not wonderful but you might have more luck with it than VS code.

Comment: Could it be related to memory limitations? How much RAM does your Macbook Air have, and how much is in use when you run your debug session? (roughly how much is in use in total by all processes, and how much specifically by the debug-related processes?) Could it be a memory thrashing problem? It might help if you provide more steps on the specifics of the program (a [mre]). Does the problem reproduce if you further simplify the program you debug? Does it reproduce for a minimal hello world program?

Comment: Have you tried the lldb-vscode adaptor instead of the lldb-mi adaptor?  lldb-mi hasn't had any real support in quite a while now.  All the active work has shifted to lldb-vscode.

Comment: So, @mevets when I run lldb from command line I don't see any source code. I'm not sure how to use it correctly. I ended up getting it set up in Xcode and debugging works fast and as expected.

Comment: @Jim Ingham I don't know how to choose an adaptor, never heard of this. Do you know how to do this in VSCode?

Comment: No, I don't personally use VSCode so I haven't had to set this up.  But a quick web search turns up a bunch of hits that look like they have instructions.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I typically use the command line building things for macos, so `cc -g ... -o prog; lldb prog`.  I've never understood why so many unix debugger insist you plant a breakpoint at main; but `b main; go <cmdlineargs>` and you should see your source.   Regardless, the fact that xcode is able to run the debugger without crazy delays twists the finger towards VS.   I've never used VS, but it must be pretty special if people are willing to put up with it being that slow.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb), I've only discovered it recently after having been frustrated with vscode cpptools debugger for the longest time as well. You just need to install the extension and change your launch config, the default `"type"` from `"cppdbg"` to `"lldb"`, and also some other keywords that may be different, e.g. `"stopAtEntry"` -> `"stopOnEntry"`, `"environment"` -> `"env"` (and note that it should be a dictionary instead of list) etc., you can refer to the [user's manual](https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/v1.10.0/MANUAL.md) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To get things up and running with Xcode 15 and macOS Sonoma, give this trick a shot:

Pop open your Terminal and punch in:

```
nano ~/.lldbinit
```

When the editor shows up, type in the following and make sure to save it:

```
settings set target.experimental.swift-enable-cxx-interop false
```

Next up, you'll want to give the `lldb-rpc-server` process a quick restart. After that, fire up your app, hook up the debugger, and throw in a breakpoint wherever you fancy in your code to see the magic happen.